# How do I remove items from the query string for redirection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

In my base page I need to remove an item from the query string and redirect. I can't use

```
Request.QueryString.Remove("foo")
```

because the collection is read-only. Is there any way to get the query string (except for that one item) without iterating through the collection and re-building it?

Comment: The reason the the querystring is read-only is that the querystring is provided by the browser. You can not do this without either iterating through the collection or just creating it again if you know all the key/value pairs that you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'd have to reconstruct the url and then redirect. Something like this:

```
string url = Request.RawUrl;

NameValueCollection params = Request.QueryString;
for (int i=0; i<params.Count; i++)
{
    if (params[i].GetKey(i).ToLower() == "foo")
    {
        url += string.Concat((i==0 ? "?" : "&"), params[i].GetKey(i), "=", params.Get(i));
    }
}
Response.Redirect(url);
```

Anyway, I didn't test that or anything, but it should work (or at least get you in thye right direction)

Comment: "without iterating through the collection" ?

Comment: Yeah, my answer is really a "you can't, you will have to rebuild it" since there's no way to do what he is asking without it. You could avoid the iteration and copy to a new array and remove the item, but you'll still have to iterate through it to create the URL to redirect to.

Answer (score 11):

You can avoid touching the original query string by working on a copy of it instead. You can then redirect the page to the a url containing your modified query string like so:

```
    var nvc = new NameValueCollection();

    nvc.Add(HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query));

    nvc.Remove("foo");

    string url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath;

    for (int i = 0; i < nvc.Count; i++)
        url += string.Format("{0}{1}={2}", (i == 0 ? "?" : "&"), nvc.Keys[i], nvc[i]);

    Response.Redirect(url);
```

**Update:**

Turns out we can simplify the code like so:

```
    var nvc = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);

    nvc.Remove("foo");

    string url = Request.Url.AbsolutePath + "?" + nvc.ToString();

    Response.Redirect(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("nextpage.aspx?{0}", Request.QueryString.ToString().Replace("foo", "mangledfoo")));
```

I quick hack, saves you little. But foo will not be present for the code awaiting it in nextpge.aspx :)

Comment: I +1'd this, I don't know who downmodded, I thought it was a reasonable hack?! :S

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. I don't see any real viable alternative to manually copying the collection since *CopyTo* will only allow you to get the values (and not the keys).

I think [HollyStyles' Hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51964/how-do-i-remove-items-from-the-query-string-for-redirection#51981) would work (although I would be nervous about putting a Replace in a QueryString - obv. dependant on use case), but there is one thing thats bothering me..

**If the target page is not reading it, why do you need to remove it from the QueryString?**

It will just be ignored?

Failing that, I think you would just need to bite the bullet and create a util method to alter the collection for you.

#### UPDATE - Following Response from OP

Ahhhh! I see now, yes, I have had similar problems with SiteMap performing full comparison of the string.

Since changing the other source code (i.e. the search) is out of the question, I would probably say it may be best to do a Replace on the string. Although to be fair, if you often encounter code similar to this, it would equally be just as quick to set up a utility function to clone the collection, taking an array of values to filter from it.

This way you would never have to worry about such issues again :)

Comment: I havent downmoded anyone in this thread yet. But a downmod is labeled "this was not helpful", and so far very few of the answers has been helpfull so I can understand why some people might downmod them

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I guess someone's gaming or having a bad day we're still in Beta afterall :) So sharing the love, +1 back.

Comment: @Espo, I was really referring to Holly's post, seemed like a reasonable hack.. Looked like someone had just come in and -1'ed everyone..

Comment: <b>
> If the target page is not reading it,
> why do you need to remove it from the
> QueryString?
</b> Excellent question. I'm using a "black box" menu control, which figures out where you are in the tree by looking at the query string. However, it does an exact string comparison, so it gets confused when there's extra stuff in the query string. The search page appends "&terms=" to the query string for highlighting, so it messes it up. Yes, rebuilding the query string and redirecting is certainly suboptimal. However, one hack is cheaper (we're a time and materials shop) for the client than re

Answer (score 2):

`HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query)` return is`QueryStringValueCollection`. It is inherit from `NameValueCollection`.

```
    var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.Url.Query);
    qs.Remove("foo"); 

    string url = "~/Default.aspx"; 
    if (qs.Count > 0)
       url = url + "?" + qs.ToString();

    Response.Redirect(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

> **The search page appends "&terms=" to the query string for highlighting, so
>   it messes it up.**

Only other option is a regex replace. If you *know for sure* that &terms is in the middle of the collection somewhere leave the trailing & in the regex, if you *know for sure* it's on the end then drop the trailing & and change the replacement string "&" to String.Empty

```
Response.Redirect(String.Format("nextpage.aspx?{0}", Regex.Replace(Request.QueryString.ToString(), "&terms=.*&", "&"));
```

Answer (score 0):

`Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)` should do this

Comment: Adding a URL to the documentation is handy too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.getleftpart.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found this was a more elegant solution

```
var qs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(Request.QueryString.ToString());
qs.Remove("item");
Console.WriteLine(qs.ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that uses LINQ against the `Request.QueryString` which allows for complex filtering of qs params if required.

The example below shows me filtering out the `uid` param to create a relative url ready for redirection.

Before: `http://www.domain.com/home.aspx?color=red&uid=1&name=bob`

After: `~/home.aspx?color=red&name=bob`

**Remove QS param from url**

```
var rq = this.Request.QueryString;
var qs = string.Join("&", rq.Cast<string>().Where(k => k != "uid").Select(k => string.Format("{0}={1}", k, rq[k])).ToArray());
var url = string.Concat("~", Request.RawUrl.Split('?')[0], "?", qs);
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you clone the collection and then redirect to the page with the cloned (and modified) collection?

I know it's not much better than iterating...